# Show a specific <div> on click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code

```js
$('.description').hide();

$('li').click(function() {
    
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
 
  $('#product-' + id).show();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li id="product-1">Product 1</li>
    <li id="product-2">Product 2</li>
    <li id="product-3">Product 3</li>
    <li id="product-4">Product 4</li>
</ul>

<div class="description-container">
    <div class="description" id="product-1">
        <h2>Product 1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde est necessitatibus illo ducimus impedit debitis facere amet, distinctio explicabo ab, qui modi molestias molestiae incidunt omnis. Quisquam, labore vero amet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="description" id="product-2">
        <h2>Product 2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio similique, explicabo voluptatibus. Id sit deserunt impedit, incidunt consequuntur quam quae, dolor non quaerat rem debitis vitae error ipsa quo dignissimos!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="description" id="product-3">
        <h2>Product 3</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi distinctio molestias culpa enim architecto optio ratione, saepe, ullam libero. Mollitia quis, ipsum similique in inventore aut officia optio quam odio?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="description" id="product-4">
        <h2>Product 4</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est distinctio nam minus unde provident, fugit doloremque minima rerum ullam nemo, rem culpa ipsa fugiat quas. Officiis error animi omnis sunt.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want is when I click on `li#product-1` , `.description-container #product-1` appears.

Same thing if I click on `li#product-2`, etc.

I try something in jQuery but it does not work.

Comment: ID **should** be _unique_

Comment: **Strictly if you can't change the HTML** use `$('.description-container ' + id).show();`

Comment: do like this, $('.description #'+id).show(); but remember ids must be uinque, try changing them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, prepending `#product-` to the the `id`s of your `li` elements will give something like `"#product-product-1"`, which won't match anything.

Even if we *did* correct that, you can't have multiple elements with the same `id` -- there's no differentiation `li#product-1` from `div#product-1`. `id`s *must* be unique; best-case, you'll select the `li` itself since it's the first match.

Instead, add a `data-...` attribute to the `li`s, and use that:

```js
$('.description').hide();

$('li').click(function() {
    
  var id = $(this).data("target");
 
  $('#product-' + id).show();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li data-target="1">Product 1</li>
    <li data-target="2">Product 2</li>
    <li data-target="3">Product 3</li>
    <li data-target="4">Product 4</li>
</ul>

<div class="description-container">
    <div class="description" id="product-1">
        <h2>Product 1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde est necessitatibus illo ducimus impedit debitis facere amet, distinctio explicabo ab, qui modi molestias molestiae incidunt omnis. Quisquam, labore vero amet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="description" id="product-2">
        <h2>Product 2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio similique, explicabo voluptatibus. Id sit deserunt impedit, incidunt consequuntur quam quae, dolor non quaerat rem debitis vitae error ipsa quo dignissimos!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="description" id="product-3">
        <h2>Product 3</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi distinctio molestias culpa enim architecto optio ratione, saepe, ullam libero. Mollitia quis, ipsum similique in inventore aut officia optio quam odio?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="description" id="product-4">
        <h2>Product 4</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est distinctio nam minus unde provident, fugit doloremque minima rerum ullam nemo, rem culpa ipsa fugiat quas. Officiis error animi omnis sunt.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Tushar Yeah, that's a better choice. I was doing a too-literal conversion of the old HTML. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you are appending the `li` `id` to `product-` which means you're looking for elements called `product-product-1`, which don't exist. Secondly your HTML has duplicate `id` attributes on the `li` and the related `div` elements which is invalid.

A better approach would be to use the `index()` from the clicked `li` to find the related `.description`. Try this:

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  $('.description').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

```css
.description {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Product 1</li>
  <li>Product 2</li>
  <li>Product 3</li>
  <li>Product 4</li>
</ul>

<div class="description-container">
  <div class="description">
    <h2>Product 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde est necessitatibus illo ducimus impedit debitis facere amet, distinctio explicabo ab, qui modi molestias molestiae incidunt omnis. Quisquam, labore vero amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    <h2>Product 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio similique, explicabo voluptatibus. Id sit deserunt impedit, incidunt consequuntur quam quae, dolor non quaerat rem debitis vitae error ipsa quo dignissimos!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    <h2>Product 3</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi distinctio molestias culpa enim architecto optio ratione, saepe, ullam libero. Mollitia quis, ipsum similique in inventore aut officia optio quam odio?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    <h2>Product 4</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est distinctio nam minus unde provident, fugit doloremque minima rerum ullam nemo, rem culpa ipsa fugiat quas. Officiis error animi omnis sunt.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _better approach would be to use the index()_, I'd prefer using `data-target="targetSelector"` and `$(this).data('target')` in handler

Comment: That would work too, however the benefit of the above approach using the `index()` is that you don't need to make any changes to the HTML or JS should `li` or `div` elements be added or removed, which is very helpful when using templating.

Comment: True, but if indexes are not proper, i.e. if any list contains extra elements, `index()` will not work as expected, although this'll work for OP code.

Comment: Of course, but like a said, when using templating in a container that will not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.description').hide();

$('li').click(function() {
    
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
 
  $('#div-'+id).show();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li id="product-1">Product 1</li>
    <li id="product-2">Product 2</li>
    <li id="product-3">Product 3</li>
    <li id="product-4">Product 4</li>
</ul>

<div class="description-container">
    <div class="description" id="div-product-1">
        <h2>Product 1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde est necessitatibus illo ducimus impedit debitis facere amet, distinctio explicabo ab, qui modi molestias molestiae incidunt omnis. Quisquam, labore vero amet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="description" id="div-product-2">
        <h2>Product 2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio similique, explicabo voluptatibus. Id sit deserunt impedit, incidunt consequuntur quam quae, dolor non quaerat rem debitis vitae error ipsa quo dignissimos!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="description" id="div-product-3">
        <h2>Product 3</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi distinctio molestias culpa enim architecto optio ratione, saepe, ullam libero. Mollitia quis, ipsum similique in inventore aut officia optio quam odio?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="description" id="div-product-4">
        <h2>Product 4</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est distinctio nam minus unde provident, fugit doloremque minima rerum ullam nemo, rem culpa ipsa fugiat quas. Officiis error animi omnis sunt.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Change the id of the description div and the selector for hiding the div.